# Why does gravity have a stronger effect on objects with more mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration

Doesn't moving something heavier require MORE force? Is it just one of those things where we just say "well that's how it works and here's some math to describe it"?

Comment: It does. But your terms are horribly imprecise which probably affects your thinking about it. "Move" doesn't mean anything. More mass = more force applied by gravity but more force to ACCELERATE. So it cancels out and everything has the same acceleration when falling (at least when the mass of the object is negligible to the planet). That's why gravity is considered an acceleration before a force. *Why* this is the case is much deeper and related to relativity and it's mysterious relationship with space-time compared to the other fundamental forces

Comment: All of physics is basically "well that's how it works and here's some math to describe it." Philosophically speaking, what else could it be?

Comment: You didn't really answer my question, I know that inertia cancels out the differences in mass when dropping something, but if I hold a 5 pound steel ball and a 1 pound steel ball, I can feel that gravity pulls the 5 pound more than the 1 pound.

Comment: @user1379857 Yeah. It's just that the way the human mind works, each deeper level of "how" is the "why" for the shallower level right above it. But they are all just "hows" in and of themselves.

Comment: @deserdoo So what exactly is your question then? I don't know if you realize this, but the title of your question has very little to do with the body of your question as written. Be more explicit  about what's running through your mind. You can edit your post. You might want to consider what the difference is, if any, between one 5lbs ball versus five 1lbs balls versus five 1lbs balls smelted into one 5lbs ball. You could reframe it as gravity just being consistent and pulling on every speck of unit mass by the same consistent amount of force whether or not it's one lump or spread out.

Comment: What I mean is that moving an object requires work, and moving a bigger object requires more work, and so if the same amount of work is applied to a heavy and light object, then they will move differently. But gravity does the opposite, it somehow applies more force on the heavy than on the light.

Comment: @deserdoo You seem to think that a 1 pound mass and a 5 pound mass should both have a 1 pound weight and therefore be accelerated differently by g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gravity is an extensive property; at any given distance-to-center, the Earth's gravity is roughly 81 times that of the moon, because the Earth is that much greater (in the gravity-field-production property of 'gravitational mass').

By Newton's third
law of motion, the fact of Earth exerting a force on a brick ensures that
the brick also exerts an equal but opposite force on the Earth.

Thus, the gravity force on the brick must, logically, be proportional
both to the mass of Earth, and the mass of the brick.   That's the
only kind of proportionality that such a force could exert that fulfills
the Newtonian law.

Newton also identified mass as a ratio of force and acceleration, in his
second law.   That, is a discovery; it DOES apparently work that way,
but since acceleration is  not exactly the same as gravity, it is
an oddity.   The 'inertial mass' of the second law seems, to
a very close approximation, to be the same as the 'gravitational mass'.

Answer (score 0):

In Newtonian physics one can consider two kinds of mass: gravitational mass (responsible for creating gravity) and inertial mass (responsible for resisting movement). We could certainly imagine that these could be different. But it appears that in our world they are the same: that the mass $m$ in $F=ma$ is the same as the mass $m$ in $F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$. Because they are the same,  they cancel, so we get $a = G\frac{M}{r^2}$, and thus the acceleration due to gravity does not depend on the mass of the object being accelerated. That is, a bigger mass needs more force to be moved, but also creates more force due to gravity by the exact same factor. You're right to wonder about this: it is a remarkable coincidence, and other forces do not work this way.

Einstein used this coincidence (the "equivalence principle") as one of the inspirations for his theory of general relativity. In relativity the equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass is not a coincidence at all. The "force" of gravity is a consequence of the shape of spacetime, and hence appears as a kind of "pseudo force" or "inertial force" similar to centrifigual force. Objects always try to follow geodesics (the general version of "straight lines") in curved spacetime, and for example near the Earth these geodesics are the paths followed by falling objects. While you're falling, you feel no force: only when you hit the ground do you feel it, and that force is due to the electromagnetic forces between the atoms in your body and the atoms in the Earth, which push you away from the curved space geodesic that your atoms are trying to follow. Now only the inertial mass (resistance to the force exerted by the Earth's atoms) needs to be considered, and hence relativity explains why the force we feel due to gravity is proportional to our inertial mass.